# PyQt5 - Polygon Shape for Custom Buttons -background issue

Tags: python, pyqt

I have the following problem. When creating the polygon, I don't get the background on transparent. I couldn't find anything on the net regarding this. If you change the style sheet, nothing will happen either. The widgets overlap. Some suggestions?

[image]
[image]

the last picture shows in which direction it should go

here is the code:

```
# --------------------- IMPORTS ----------------------- #
from PyQt5 import QtGui                               #
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QPoint  #
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPolygon
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *                           #
# ----------------------------------------------------- #


class Shape(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(Shape, self).__init__(parent)

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        painter.setPen(QtGui.QPen(Qt.black, 1, Qt.SolidLine))

        points = QPolygon([
            QPoint(0, 200),     # bottom x - start
            QPoint(100, 200),   # bottom x - end
            QPoint(200, 0),     # top  x - start
            QPoint(100,0)       # tpü  x - end
        ])

        painter.drawPolygon(points)

class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        lay = QHBoxLayout(self)

        for x in range(3):
            poly = Shape(self)
            poly.setStyleSheet("background:rgba(0,0,0,0);")

            lay.addWidget(poly)




if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.setMinimumSize(500, 500)
    mw.show()
    app.exec()
```

Comment: Widget always have rectangular shapes and cannot overlap like this if placed into a layout. Also, QWidget subclasses ignore the stylesheet colors unless painting through QStyle or by setting the `WA_StyledBackground` attribute. To achieve what you're trying to do, you either create your own container (implementing the widget reposition), or use a QGraphicsView with custom QGraphicsItems. Alternatively, use a single QWidget that contains all painted objects.

Comment: But with a "new" container, would the widgets still be apart? because the new container is also rectangular. Do you have an example? (no whole code for that) which one can look at?

Comment: As said, if you create a container for those widgets, you are responsible of their positioning so that they can properly overlap. If also the container has to use that shape, then you also need another parent container that is able to do the same. If the structure is going to be more complex, then the Graphics View framework is more appropriate.

Comment: @musicamante Wouldn't overlapping grid-layout spans work for this? I think if in the example `lay` was changed to a `QGridLayout`, then something like `lay.addWidget(poly, 0, x * 2, 1, 5)` should make things more-or-less line up okay.

Comment: @ekhumoro I thought about that, but the problem comes when computing the *proper* spacing: it would require to compute and set fixed minimum size for all columns (both for the common columns and for the indivual ones) to ensure that widgets don't actually overlap. Considering the situation, I see little benefit in using a layout: the layout cannot be smaller, and it should not be larger; at that point, setting fixed geometries for the children (and minimum size for the parent) would suffice.

Comment: in any case, thank you for worrying about it. couldn't find anything until now